# Can we convert (marshal) java objects with variables of 'Object' data type using JAXB

Tags: java, xml, object, jaxb, marshalling

I have Class with variables which have 'Object' data type. I have to use the Object data type  because the data type of that filed is unknown. (Sometimes it is a String, String Array, Or other custom object etc.). But when we use 'Object' the JAXB Marshalling process is failing with errors.
Is there a way to handle this ?

My class is similar to below

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "student")
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Student {

    private String name;
    private int id;
    private Object subject;
```

}

when I use the @XmlTransient for the 'Object subject'. Marshalling errors are not available. But it does not add the 'subject' filed to the XML file.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that there is no direct way to handle the above situation if you do not know the Data type/types that can be assigned to 'Object' type variable.
But if you know all the data types that can be assigned to the 'Object' variable you can use [@XMLElements](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlElements.html) annotation.